# Delegate method in Swift, fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am trying to implement a delegate method in Swift.

This is the error I get: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

What am I doing wrong??

```
import UIKit

protocol myProtocol {
    func appendName(name: String)
}

class MyArrayStore: NSObject, myProtocol {
    var myArray: [String] = ["Apple", "Carrot", "Orange"]
    func appendName(name: String) {
        myArray.append(name)
        println("\(myArray)")
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let myArrStore = MyArrayStore()

    var myDelegate: myProtocol!

    @IBAction func addName(sender: UIButton) {
        let name = "John"
        myDelegate!.appendName(name) // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    }
}
```

I initialize MyArrayStore class in AppDelegate in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching:

```
var myStore: MyArrayStore = MyArrayStore()
```

Answer (score 0):

change myDelegate!.appendName(name) for myArrStore.appendName(name)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this occurs because your never set your `myDelegate`. And than you will get a crash by calling `myDelegate!.appendName(name)` because `myDelegate` is `nil`.

But Please read some basic concepts first:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

first -> Search for "Delegation"

Comment: I have been reading the Swift documentation many times but I can not find how you **set** `myDelegate`. Except at `var myDelegate: myProtocol?` I have tried everything but always get Xcode errors or i get nil. Please show me how, if you would be so kind. I don't initialize `MyArrayStore class` in ViewController, is an error left over from all experiments!